Electric field due to plane at constant potential and a cylinder with no flux on surface

There is a plate at a constant potential V and potential equal to zero far away. the problem is two-dimensional. For this case, the electric field lines will simply be straight lines. Now let there be a cylinder of radius R with its centre at a distance L from the plate. The boundary condition of the cylinder surface is no electric flux passes through it. Now, the field lines will bend around the cylinder. I have qualitatively drawn them in the figure below.
Is there any analytical solution for this problem? The method of images typically employs constant potential over spheres/cylinders, but here, the boundary condition is zero flux rather than constant potential.
